# Prevent Flickering for moving object

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a breakout game for an assignment in windows form and I've made games before, but I've just not used winforms before. I've found things that are supposed to help like `OnPaint()` (which you're supposed to override), `DoubleBuffered and`Invalidate`. But I'm just struggling applying it to my code

Here's what I have:

```
 int xSpeed, ySpeed;

    Graphics display;
    Brush brush;

    Rectangle ballRect;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 1;

        xSpeed = 5;
        ySpeed = 5;
        ballRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);

        display = this.CreateGraphics();

        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        ballRect.X += xSpeed;
        ballRect.Y += ySpeed;

        if (ballRect.X >= 469)
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;

        if (ballRect.Y >= 457)
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        if (ballRect.X <= 0)
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;

        if (ballRect.Y <= 0)
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        display.Clear(Color.White);
        display.FillEllipse(brush, ballRect);

    }
```

I'm drawing the ball in Update method (timer1_tick), but I feel like I shouldn't be. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Don't store the Graphic object.  Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the control's paint event and use the Graphic object from that.  Set the form's DoubleBuffered property to true.

Comment: DoubleBuffered can cause an issue on Windows 10 see: [Redraw issue on Windows10 with DoubleBuffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51824224/7713750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom `Control` or `Form` and:

- In constructor Set styles for flicker free painting `OptimizedDoubleBuffer`, `UserPaint`, `AllPaintingInWmPaint`
- In constructor Set style for redraw if the size changes `ResizeRedraw`
- In `Tick` event just update position of ball and then `Invalidate` the control
- override `OnPaint` method of your control and put the paint logic there
- Also you should use properties for speed or ball size, to be able to invalidate the control if those values changed. (I didn't implement properties in below code.) Also you can increase the interval a little.

For example:

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 1;

        xSpeed = 5;
        ySpeed = 5;

        ballRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, ballRect);
    }

    int xSpeed, ySpeed;
    Brush brush;
    Rectangle ballRect;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ballRect.X += xSpeed;
        ballRect.Y += ySpeed;

        if (ballRect.X + ballRect.Width >= this.Width)
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;

        if (ballRect.Y + ballRect.Height >= this.Height)
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        if (ballRect.X <= 0)
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;

        if (ballRect.Y <= 0)
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        this.Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help - there's no more flickering now.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback:)

Comment: When I tried to do it said I didn't have enough reputation, but I must have enough now (:/) So I've voted it :)

Comment: When you receive up vote for your question you gain +5 reputation, Also by accepting an answer you gain +2.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is happening because you are drawing directly to the display.  First you clear the display, which the user will see for a split second, then you draw a circle over it, which is only displayed for a short time before the process repeats.  That "overdrawing" is where the flicker is coming from.

One method to get rid of it is to do all your drawing to a memory bitmap and, once complete, move the entire bitmap to the display.

Once other issue I see with your code is that you create a `Graphics` instance in the constructor and keep it around for the life of the program.  That's a pattern that you should avoid.  Instead you should create a new Graphics object, preferably in a `using` statement for each "frame".  That will make sure that everything is getting cleaned up properly.